# Ubuntu lock screen with running apps in the back instead of a wallpaper

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, desktop-background, screensaver

In Ubuntu (latest version) is it possible to have a lock screen overlaying whatever I'm doing in the background versus having a wallpaper as the background? For example if I'm browsing on stackoverflow, when I lock my laptop I want the lock screen password prompt to appear above the stackoverflow page not above a wallpaper. Also if possible notifications could be live/visible.